# Не могу разобраться, почему функция не возвращает значение из другой функции

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

```js
function getXMLListMatches() {
var URL = 'http://www.nowgoal.group/gf/data/goal8.xml';
let getistMatches = request(URL, function (err, res, body) {
if (err) throw err;
let a = parseString(body, function (err, result) {
    let resultsBody = result['c']['ids'][0].split(',').slice(0, -1);
    console.log(resultsBody)
    return resultsBody
    });
    return a;
});
return getistMatches;
};

let a = getXMLListMatches()
console.log(a)
```

Никак не могу разобраться, почему не могу получить переменную resultsBody в итоге. return возвращает либо ничего, либо ошибку.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что у вас отображается в логе?

Comment: @karvetskiy я отредактировал вопрос и добавил скриншот

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить правила Content Security Policy в файле *manifest*, добавив `style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'`:

```
"content_security_policy": "default-src 'self' style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
```

Это позволит использовать inline стиль.

*Оригинал:*
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766817/refused-to-apply-inline-style-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security